# whats the meaning of getting "b' ' " in answer and how can I overcome it?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, gsm, sim900

I am working on automation project which can control through raspberry pi and GSM module, but unfortunately while i am trying below python code I am not getting exact message that I need to get,
while I execute  my code and print my received message that time I am only getting *b''* in reply, 
so , could anybody help me out this , how can I resolve this problem?

for an example , my send message is "LED1" and in reply I am getting "b' '" at print(message) section and then after without checking condition it directly execute "try again" condition.

```
import serial

import time

import os

ser = serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyS0", 9600, timeout=0) #9600 is the default for SIM900A modem


ser.write(('AT+CMGF=1\r').encode('utf-8'))   
time.sleep(1) 

ser.write(('AT+CMGDA="DEL ALL"\r').encode('utf-8')) 

time.sleep(1)

message = ser.read(ser.inWaiting()) # inWaiting- get the number of bytes in the inout buffer

print (message)

while true:
      if message == 'LED1':

      print ("LED 1 is on")

  elif message == "LED2":

      print ("LED 2 is on")

  elif messsage == 'EXIT':

      print ("shuting down")

      ser.close ()

      break

  else:

      print ("Try again")


ser.close() #close the serial port
```

`

Comment: You have issues with your indentation. e.g. the line `if message == 'LED1':`

Comment: Hi Rakesh I am geting error before that line when I want to print my received message.